# when i run project it shows controller does not exit in laravel , but it there in controllers folder what i do?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

**SampleController.php ,web.php, example.blade.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SampleController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return view('example');
    }
    
}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/',function () {
  
  return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/sample', 'SampleController@index');
```

**example.blade.php**

```
<?php
echo 'hello world !!';
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please include the error that you receive and what version of Laravel are you using

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using Laravel 8 and its now updated,

```
use App\Http\Controllers\SampleController;

Route::get('/sample', [SampleController::class, 'index']);
```

Pls check further details here,
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: How you are sure he is using Laravel 8.x?

Comment: I am sure, this approach has been updated in laravel 8 now,